# Magento Product View Details Not loading Properly

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, product

In my magento website, whenever i am trying to view the product details page,its not loading the product details page properly,after the Product Image its not displaying anything.

[image]

Comment: If you view source on the page, does it just end, or do you get an error?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this Issue following way.

**1: Modify php.ini**

Edit php.ini .Search `memory_limit` in your `php.ini`, and change the value of it. If no memory_limit found, add the following line at the end of `php.ini`
`memory_limit = 128M ; /* Change the 128M to your needs */`

**2 : htaccess Way**

Find the ".htaccess" in your root directory of the specified domain, if there isn't, create one. Put the following line in it.
`php_value memory_limit 128M; /* Change the 128M to your needs */`

**3: Change Memory At Runtime**

PHP memory limit could be changed at runtime. Via this way, you have no need to change and configuration of your server environment.
`ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');`

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

there is php error on that go to your page `index.php` remove `#` from then it will show the error.

`#ini_set('display_errors', 1);`